RStudio: Failure to install 'imager'
I am attempting to do the tutortial "Getting started with imager", but the very first instruction library(imager) generates a long error message, with only the first part shown below
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘imager’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib

My versions of R and RStudio are up to date, as is my Mac.
Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Please provide the full error message and confirm that you have  installed imager successfully.  [Does "imager" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) return TRUE or FALSE?]

Have you tried re-installing by running install.packages("imager")? What is the output of that? The package does have some system dependencies that R cannot install itslef: fftw3, libtiff, and X11.

Thank you Limey.  "imager" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) returns TRUE

I tried the full error message but it is too long.  I will try new post with the fulle error message.     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘imager’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/imager/libs/imager.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
Referenced from: <0D2C2E04-7501-3DE8-9893-DC00CD84A8D5> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Reso

Thank you MrFlick. install.packages("imager") returns The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/rp/46fydhhj6_z7f7m_hw1f2b280000gn/T//Rtmp8kJMfo/downloaded_packages

MrFlick, must I therefore try installing  fftw3, libtiff, and X11 by hand?  Thank you.

Already tried installing XQuartz?

Thank you, jay.sf!  XQuartz did the trick.  I have now tried several of imager's functions and everything has worked thus fare.  Thank you!
